# Check if in localstorage has same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

This part of my code has a bug that when I click on "-" img it deletes the name storaged, but if I click again, this time a "+" img, it instead of returns the div from the fade, it create a new div with the same value, and then I have two divs and two keys with the same value.

```
function fade(id) {

    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var arr = new Array();   

$('.qualquer').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).text());
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(element).toggle(
        function a(){
        $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.5, function(){
            $("<img id='maix"+ide+"'>").attr('src', 'pics/+.gif')
            .appendTo(element)
            .addClass("minus3");
            localStorage.removeItem('artist'+id);            
        })
    },
        function b(){
        $(element).fadeTo("fast", 1, function(){
            $("#maix"+ide+"").remove();
            localStorage.setItem('artist'+id,arr[id]);   
        })
    });
    });   
}
```

HTML, it is generate on javascript, thats why those plus:

```
"<div class='qualquer' id='"+(div+i)+"'>" + "<div onClick=location.href='artistinfo.html' class='diveText'> " + reals[i] + "</div>" + "<div class='diveImg'>" + "<img src='pics/-.png' id='"+(img+i)+"' onClick='fade(this.id)' class='minus'>" + "</div>" + "</div>"
```

Have I being clear enough?

Comment: Why don't you remove the bug?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I'll edit the question with the code that makes it wrong.

Comment: Put also your HTML please

Comment: These $("#maix"+ide+"") and $("<img id='maix"+ide+"'>") shouldn't have id instead of ide? The div is appearing cause your are appending it on your <img> tag when it is removed. Right?

Comment: this ide is a variable I create out of the function. I append the img with the Id, then I remove it. This part it about a img, what repeats is the div. idk

Answer (score 1):

Firstly verify with this

```
var isExist = !!localStorage.getItem('localStorageVariableName');
```

So, if you get false create it

```
localStorage.setItem('localStorageVariableName', value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't know what specific key is, may be anyone. I'll post the code.

Comment: You have a list of names on your localStorage and you don't know the Key's name, that's interesting,

Comment: I know the keys, but not the one that will be repeated.

Comment: Edit your question with your code, then I can help you better.

Comment: I did that, try to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to check if a value exists in localStorage:

```
Storage.prototype.hasValue = function(v) {

    for(var prop in this) 
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && localStorage[prop] === v) return true;
    return false;
}

localStorage.setItem('test', 'testing 1');
localStorage.setItem('test2', 'testing 2');
localStorage.setItem('test3', 'testing 3');

console.log(localStorage.hasValue('testing 1'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AL6Mk/1/